# Prompt for root access in cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, root-access

I want my program to begin with a prompt/alert that asks for root access. The user must enter their password, and then the application follows. I've been looking around, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

You help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[This is Apple's documentation on the matter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/authorization_ref.pdf), and [here is a good example of it](https://github.com/potionfactory/LetsMove/blob/2b13778d3b3ae2515c8d7e71fe60dd063412f50d/PFMoveApplication.m#L419-L491).

Answer (score 2):

Use BLAuthentication. Its much easier to launch authorization as root and you can enter bash commands to run as root.

http://jim.roepcke.com/blog/archives/2002/09/24/blauthentication-class.html