# Spawn Authentication Window on macOS to Initiate Sudo Command from C++

Tags: c++, macos

I have a C++ script that is checking for an update and if found installing it.

In order to install the update it's going to have to request sudo/admin access. At the moment I have it
executing command

```
std::string command = "sudo install -pkg /path/to/pkg -target /" 
system(command.c_str())
```

However, it requests the sudo creds in terminal which a normal user wouldn't see. How can I spawn an authentication window in order to authenticate the install?

This could be entirely the wrong approach, so if there is a better way please do say.

Comment: Looks like you have to drop down to Objective-C for this, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066864/prompt-for-root-access-in-cocoa-application

Comment: thank you @PaulSanders I hadn't found that question